# Android gridview example

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview, sdk

i have been trying to apply the [Gridview Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) but i'm stuck in an error, i know it will be easy but i can not get it though, i'm still so beginner, anyway here is the error :

```
  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the ( setOnItemClickListener ) have a red line under it as well as ( OnItemClickListener ) and ( HelloGridView ) ....
could anyone please which way i went wrong ... ?

note :

**my project name is : GridView1**

i'm using eclpise and android skd 15

i have already made the ( ImageAdapter.Java ) Class - Fine

i dunno what is wrong so far .... help

Comment: Pass the cursor over the red line (or the red mark to the left of it) and it will show you which is the error. If that does not help you, write it here so we know what is wrong). Also, paste more of your code (ideally, write a program as small as possible that causes the same error and post it here completely)

Comment: Have you imported   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;  Or press CTRL+Shift+O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting red line below **setOnItemClickListener** and **OnItemClickListener** that means you are not importing proper classes so try to first **import all required classes** (in eclipse that is **ctrl+shift+o in eclipse(windows)**).

But one thing that you are telling is that you also getting red line below **HelloGridView** ,however this should not happen(because this is class name and **HelloGridView .this** will be context(this is very basic but as you said you are new I am telling you)) kindly check your class whether it is **extending to Activity** or not like this

**HelloGridView extends Activity**

If you have done this thing also, kindly check for required jar files that your application needs, you can check this by right click your project **Java Build Path ->Order and export**
select your api(contains jar file,if not selected) press **select all** button and press **OK** and you are done then.

If still you do not get classes that you required you clean your project that is **Project -> clean**

Answer (score 0):

You need to import OnItemClickListener

add following import statement

import 
android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Answer (score 0):

do as @jitendra says or alternatively do so:

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener() {...}
```

Notice the use of `View` to fully qualify the `OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Thanx yo all .....
problems were :
1) I used Copy and Paste to run the project and i forgot that i created it with a different name (GridView1) instead of (HelloGridView) .
2) i did not Import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener as mayur said "thanx to him"